# How come a lot of people have a reputation of 101?

Tags: support, reputation

Starting at [page 5 of the users list](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users?page=5&tab=) a lot of people have a repuration of 101. Continuing to [page 20](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users?page=20&tab=)! (At this moment).

It doesn't look like those people did that much, most picks have no activity at all. Where did they get this from?

(I'm not jealous or something :) Just interested.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They registered at another Stack Exchange site, got over 200 rep there, then registered at SO. They got +100 reputation for registering on both.

Comment: It's 200 rep, but otherwise correct.

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks, I've updated it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!